# Harris HDL example 4.13

Tags: boolean, logic, verilog, system-verilog

I read a book called "Digital design and computers architecture" written by Harris and I have a question about example 4.13 (logic gates with delays).

In that example we build a model for the expression **Y = !A*!B*!C + A*!B*!C + A*!B*C.** And also, we add a few delays to it: 1ns for inverters, three-input AND gates have a delay of 2ns, three-input OR gates have a delay of 4 ns.

Now, the .sv-code below:

```
*timescale 1ns/1ps
module example(input a,b,c
               output y);
logic ab,bb,cb,n1,n2,n3;
assign #1 {ab,bb,cb} = ~{a,b,c};
assign #2 n1 = ab & bb & cb;
assign #2 n2 = a & bb & cb;
assign #2 n3 = a & bb & c;
assign #4 y = n1 | n2 | n3;

endmodule
```

So, the question is: what is the logic of such form of programming 3 operands (!A*!B*!C , A*!B*!C , A*!B*C). I don't understand what's happening on the lines from 4 to 8.

Can anyone explain please? Why there are such operands like ab, bb and cb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ab`, `bb`, and `cb` are all the logical inverses of `a`, `b`, and `c` (ie, `!A`, `!B`, and `!C` from your logical expression). The "b" or "_B" suffix is often used to indicate the inverse or inverse assertion level.

The `assign` expression each represent an operation from the original boolean equation:

```
assign #1 {ab,bb,cb} = ~{a,b,c};
```

This expression can be thought of as 3 NOT gates with inputs `a`, `b`, and `c`, with outputs `ab`, `bb`, and `cb` respectively. It uses the Verilog bitwise inverse operator `~` as well as the Verilog concatenation operator `{}` to do the inverse all in one line rather than 3 separate `assign` expressions.

From there, the assignments of `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` all correspond to the 3, 3-way and operations in the equation and simply serve as intermediate values in the expression. `n1` gets assigned `!A * !B * !C`, `n2` gets `A * !B * !C` and `n3` gets `A * !B * C`. Notice that each of these has the delay `#n` for the given gate, with the inverses gets `#1`; `n1`, `n2` and `n3` getting `#2` and finally the output `y` being assigned with the `#4` delay as its the final 3-way OR of the ANDed values `n1`, `n2`, `n3`.

Comment: So, `ab` is not the AND-operation between `a` and `b`? Is the `b` in this operand just a symbol, that indicates the inverse? It's very strange in that way, because there was no such explanation in the book before this example. The only inversion symbol given in the book was `~`.

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln In the code above, no, the variable `ab` is not the AND of `a` and `b`, but is the inverse. True, the `b` suffix is a bit strange; Im not sure where it came from but Im sure theres a history there. Other symbols for not include ~A, /A, nA, A# (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_level#Active_state), but In Verilog, the `~` is the bitwise inverse operator with `!` being the logical operator just as in C.